# Generating sudoku 'boxes' from rows - prolog

Tags: prolog, sudoku, do-while, clpfd, sublist

I'm trying to write a simple program that just checks whether or not an input sudoku board is *currently* incorrect; i.e. it has two of the same numbers in a row, column or 'box'. 
I haven't run into any trouble with the rows and columns part - a fairly straight forward task, which I accomplish with the following code (it should be noted that '0' represents a square that has not been filled in):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

%Takes a matrix, determines if any row has repeating numbers
check([H|T]):-
    all_diff(H),
    check(T).
check([]).

%takes a list, checks if it contains repetitions other than '0'.
all_diff([]).
all_diff([X|Xs]) :-
    ( X = 0 ->
    all_diff(Xs)
        ;
        \+memberchk(X, Xs),
      all_diff(Xs)

    ).

consistent(Rows):-
    check(Rows),                %verify rows are free of repeats
    transpose(Rows,Columns),    %L1 represents columns
    check(Columns),         %verify all columns are free of repeats
        [H|T] = Rows,
        length(H,M),
    K is integer(sqrt(M)).     %this will give me dimensions of each box (KxK)
```

However, I'm not quite as clear on how to go about generating the lists that will represent the KxK 'boxes' (where K is the square root of the length of a row). 
I get the value of K, and I think I would like to do something along the lines of partitioning row1 into K sublists, and then appending row2's K sublists to the end of row1's sublists until I reach row(K*K).

Unfortunately, I'm really not sure how to go about making this happen? Is there a BIP I can use that will do something along the lines of taking a list and breaking it into X lists each of length Y?

Otherwise, any ideas? I know a *tiny* but about dowhile loops, and I suppose they could be implemented here, but I'm not really sure how I would do that either?
Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

a simple, not efficient way could use index arithmetic and loops:

```
...
    Sq = 3,
    findall(B, (between(1, Sq, R),
            between(1, Sq, C),
            block(M, Sq, R, C, B)), Bs).

cell(M, R,C, V) :-
    nth1(R,M,Row), nth1(C,Row,V).

block(M, Sq, R,C, B) :-
    findall(V, (between(1, Sq, X),
            between(1, Sq, Y),
            I is (R-1) * Sq + X,
            J is (C-1) * Sq + Y,
            cell(M, I, J, V)), B).
```

In [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.7%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/clpfd.html%27%29%29) of library(clpfd)  there is a more efficient way, limited to known standard dimension. You could try to generalize that code.

**edit** here is my test case: please note the matrix it's fake, just make easy to understand where blocks are.

```
q(Bs) :-
    M = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
         [a,b,c,d,_,3,_,8,5],
         [x,y,z,_,2,_,_,_,_],
         [u,v,z,e,t,y,_,_,_],
         [b,b,b,e,t,y,1,_,_],
         [c,c,c,e,t,y,_,_,_],
         [5,_,_,_,_,_,_,7,3],
         [_,_,2,_,1,_,_,_,_],
         [_,_,_,_,4,_,_,_,9]],

    Sq = 3,
    findall(B, (between(1, Sq, R),
            between(1, Sq, C),
            block(M, Sq, R, C, B)), Bs).

cell(M, R,C, V) :-
    nth1(R,M,Row), nth1(C,Row,V).

block(M, Sq, R,C, B) :-
    findall(V, (between(1, Sq, X),
            between(1, Sq, Y),
            I is (R-1) * Sq + X,
            J is (C-1) * Sq + Y,
            cell(M, I, J, V)), B).
```

and test with this command:

```
?- q(Bs),maplist(writeln,Bs).
[1,2,3,a,b,c,x,y,z]
[4,5,6,d,_G928,3,_G934,2,_G940]
[7,8,9,_G895,8,5,_G904,_G907,_G910]
[u,v,z,b,b,b,c,c,c]
[e,t,y,e,t,y,e,t,y]
[_G796,_G799,_G802,1,_G808,_G811,_G814,_G817,_G820]
[5,_G769,_G772,_G775,_G778,2,_G784,_G787,_G790]
[_G736,_G739,_G742,_G745,1,_G751,_G754,4,_G760]
[_G706,7,3,_G715,_G718,_G721,_G724,_G727,9]
Bs = [[1, 2, 3, a, b, c, x, y|...], [4, 5, 6, d, _G928, 3, _G934|...], [7, 8, 9, _G895, 8, 5|...], [u, v, z, b, b|...], [e, t, y, e|...], [_G796, _G799, _G802|...], [5, _G769|...], [_G736|...], [...|...]].
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm wondering, however, if you would mind perhaps helping me to understand whats going on here a bit better? The betweens nested within the findall seem to be giving me some confusion! 
It does seem, however, like Bs should be the list containing the list of 'blocks' (I might be missing something?), but it seems to always end up as [[],[],[],[]]. Any idea what might be going on there? Thanks again for the help - I really appreciate it!